# Redirect when already log in

Tags: laravel, redirect, authentication, laravel-5

i am using laravel 5.2. when i visit `www.example.com/` will redirect to login page, and after im logged in and visit `www.example.com/` again i got a login page again. I want to redirect to `www.example.com/index` if the user visit already login.
how to redirect to spesific page if user already login when visiting `www.example.com/` ?
thanks before

Comment: Laravel 5.2 ? Why are you using the development branch for your application ? Just curious to know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (Auth::check()) {
 // User is already on login
 return redirect('/index');
}
```

Put Auth::check() on controller method. [See This.](http://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user)

Comment: thanks bro, i put `Auth::check()` on my route.

`Route::get('/', function () {
 if (Auth::check()) {
        return Redirect::to('index');
        }
      else{
  return view('login');}
});`

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. I guess you need sessions to keep you logged in or else you keep on logging in every time you visit the page.

Comment: can you give me an example ?